# Firebase Hosting i18n rewrites not working

Tags: firebase, internationalization, firebase-hosting

Firebase has recently(Aug 20, 2020) [announced](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/firebase-hosting-new-features.html) support for [i18n rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites).

My web app has two locales: English and French, so I've put the French content under `public/localized/fr/` and the English content under `public`. Then, I added the following to `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    ...
  },
  "i18n": {
    "root": "/localized"
  }
}
```

However, if I set French as my primary language in the browser settings(and the value of the `Accept-Language` header is `fr`), the website still serves the English content.

I have created an MCVE: https://github.com/Jaimies/firebase-hosting-i18n-rewrites-demo.

---

I'm using Firebase CLI version `8.9.0`.

**Update:** I filed a bug report to Firebase support.
**Update 2:** I got a response from Firebase support, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63630543/11105280).

Comment: Since this appears to be a Firebase Hosting bug, I'd recommend reaching out to [support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs). Can you also include your Firebase CLI version and the exact `Accept-Language` header being sent in the request when it's not working?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh The CLI version is `8.9.0`, and the `Accept-Language` value is `fr`. I've also edited the question to include that information. I'll create a bug report in the near-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i18n` attribute in your `firebase.json` is placed at the root, while it should be inside the `hosting` attribute.
So you have to change `firebase.json` to the following:

```
{
 "hosting": {
    ...
    "i18n": {
     "root": "/localized"
   }
 }
}
```

---

Thanks to Eder from Firebase support for pointing this issue out.

Comment: Hi - I'm an engineer on Firebase Hosting - this is correct. :)